# Colon expected error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple problem.

```
class MyObj:
   ...
   def get_file_name(self):
    return "myfile.txt" 

some_obj = MyObj()

# Error: Colon expected
with open some_obj.get_file_name() as f:
  print("dealing with file ...")
  # do something on f
```

`MyObj` class has a method called `get_file_name(self)`, which returns a string of file name.

In the code of opening the file, I got compiler error **Colon expected**. I don't see where/why colon needed. Please help me why I got this error?

Comment: bad syntax in your code, try adding brackets when opening your file:

Comment: I did not get the error. However line 9 should be this `with open(some_obj.get_file_name()) as f:`. You where missing parentheses in the `open()` function.

Comment: The traceback is one of the most helpful debugging tools.  If you would post that, I would be more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
with open some_obj.get_file_name() as f:
```

should be:

```
with open(some_obj.get_file_name()) as f:
```

That is, `open()` is a function!

Answer (score 0):

bad syntax in your code, try adding brackets when opening your file:

```
# Error: Colon expected
with open(some_obj.get_file_name()) as f:
    print("dealing with file ...")
    # do something on f
```

Comment: Actually, `()` are usually called _parentheses_. Brackets would be `[]`.